# Swashbuckle + ASP.Net Core WebApi: Swagger Document does not include Request-Header or QueryParameter for version selection?

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I use ASP.Net Core WebApi, Swashbuckle and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning to document and versioning my API.

The versioning also works so far.

**My Problem:**

The generated Swagger UI Document does not include parameters (Request-Header or Query Parameter) to determine the version of the Endpoint. So when i press "Execute" in the Swagger-Document the wrong version (default version) is picked for the endpoint.

**To be precise:**

Swagger executes this request: https://localhost:5001/values

But, it should execute this requerst: https://localhost:5001/values?api-version=2.0

[image]

**Code:**

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[SwaggerTag("Gets some values. Have fun with it")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    public ValuesController()
    {
    }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets all values
  /// </summary>
  /// <remarks>There are values from 1 to 10</remarks>
  /// <returns></returns>
  [HttpGet]
  [SwaggerResponse(200, "Request was successful a list of values was returned", typeof(int[]))]
  [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
  {
        return Ok(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets all values
  /// </summary>
  /// <remarks>There are values from 1 to 20</remarks>
  /// <returns></returns>
  [HttpGet]
  [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Values", "Changed Endpoints" })]
  [SwaggerResponse(200, "Request was successful a list of values was returned", typeof(int[]))]
  [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Getv2()
  {
        return Ok(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 });
  }
```

Enable versioning:

```
        services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
        {
            config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            config.ReportApiVersions = true;

            config.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new QueryStringApiVersionReader(),
             new HeaderApiVersionReader()
             {
                 HeaderNames = { "x-api-version" }
             });
        });
```

Enable SwaggerGen:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("1.0", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "API v1.0",
                Version = "1.0",
            });
            c.SwaggerDoc("2.0", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "API v1.0",
                Version = "1.0",
            });
            c.EnableAnnotations();
            c.IncludeXmlComments(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "OpenApi.xml"));
            c.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
            {
                if (!apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo)) return false;

                var versions = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                    .OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MapToApiVersionAttribute>()
                    .SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions).ToList();

                return versions.Any(v => v.ToString() == docName);
            });
        });
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by adding:

```
     services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
        {
            options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            options.DefaultApiVersionParameterDescription = "Do NOT modify api-version!";
        });
```

The parameters are now added. But unfortunately no default value is filled automatically. Anyone have an idea?

[image]